# UnicodeDecode 'ascii' error on end of file

Tags: python

I'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 24245: ordinal not in range(128)` on multiple files, for all of which the position given is basically the end of the file. `Chardet.detect()` gives me ASCII as the codec with 1.0 confidence.

Does anyone know what encoding this should probably be? This file was written in windows so I assume that has something to do with it.

Edit: Removed hex dump.

Comment: No, no one knows the encoding of a file we can't look at.  Reduce one of the files small enough to post here that reproduces the issue.  The encoding could be anything, and even seeing it could be an educated guess.

Comment: Also, did you feed `chardet` the whole file or just a portion?  It shouldn't detect ASCII with 100% confidence with an 0x84 byte in it.  I tested with a 100K ASCII file with an 0x84 appended to the end and got `windows-1252` with .73 confidence.

Comment: Opening the file to cut it down and save it "takes care" of the issue. However, there were 140+ of these files to take care of so this wasn't my preferred method. Feeding the entire file to chardet seems to work, although the encodings seem to be all over the place.

Comment: Note that `windows-1252` will work for any file that doesn't contain 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90 or 0x9D, so it isn't necessarily correct.  Character 0x84 isn't a commonly used Windows-1252 character either.  Again, being able to see the file might give people a better guess.  Make sure to include a portion of the file that has the 0x84 character.  A hexdump would be ideal.  What localized version of Windows were the files created on?

Comment: Removed hex dump. I figured out where the strange characters were coming from–encrypted passwords (hence the file removal). Chardet seems to be doing okay if I just let it read the entire file, so I'm going to stick with that.